# Visual Studio para de rodar ao avaliar variável

Tags: visual-studio-2015, debug

Fazendo alguns testes em um sistema antigo, cheguei em um comportamento estranho pro parte do Visual Studio. Quando passo o mouse em cima de uma variável de um tipo específico, o Visual Studio fecha, como podem ver no GIF abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(Note que interrogações aparecem no nome das propriedades por alguns instantes.

A princípio, pensei que ele tivesse entrado em algum tipo de loop no `get` de alguma propriedade, mas coloquei breakpoints em todas as propriedades da classe e isso não aconteceu.

O objeto que eu avalio de início é do tipo:

```
List<EntrevDeslig.Planilha> listaDados = new List<EntrevDeslig.Planilha>();
```

E os atributos do objeto `Planilha` são os seguintes:

```
    private string _nomeplan;
    public string sNomePlan { get { return _nomeplan; } set { _nomeplan = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }

    private string _tituloplan {  get { return _tituloplan; } set { _tituloplan = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }
    public string sTituloPlan;

    private string _grade;
    public string sGrade { get { return _grade; } set { _grade = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }

    private string _quesito;
    public string sQuesito { get { return _quesito; } set { _quesito = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }

    private string _dataini;
    public string sSdataIni { get { return _dataini; } set { _dataini = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }

    private string _datafim;
    public string sSdataFim { get { return _datafim; } set { _datafim = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }

    private string _grupocar;
    public string sGrupoCar { get { return _grupocar; } set { _grupocar = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }

    private string _cargo;
    public string sCargo { get { return _cargo; } set { _cargo = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }

    private string _datareg;
    public string sSdataReg { get { return _datareg; } set { _datareg = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }

    private string _chave;
    public string sChave { get { return _chave; } set { _chave = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }
    public int iOrdem;

    private string _titulo;
    public string sTitulo { get { return _titulo; } set { _titulo = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }

    private string _titulopai;
    public string sTituloPai { get { return _titulopai; } set { _titulopai = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }

    private string _processo;
    public string sProcesso { get { return _processo; } set { _processo = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }

    private string _nivel;
    public string sNivel { get { return _nivel; } set { _nivel = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }

    public string BCOID;
    public string sOPC;
```

O problema acontece apenas quando avalio a classe Planilha, não a lista.

Alguém teve algum problema semelhante? Ou pelo menos sabe alguma maneira de identificar a causa do problema (logs do VS, algo assim..)? O sistema funciona perfeitamente em ambiente de produção, mas gostaria de corrigir isso, ou pelo menos entender

Comment: Já verificou se é alguma Extensão? Já tive um problema semelhante, e ao desativar as extensões, identifiquei uma que quando ativada, não deixava debugar normalmente. Não lembro o nome da extensão.

Comment: @ismael eu não uso nenhuma extensão, e é apenas nesse objeto `Planilha` que isso acontece

Comment: A única coisa de anormal que vi nos atributos, é o `get` e `set` na variável privada. `private string _tituloplan {  get { return _tituloplan; } set { _tituloplan = value.Replace("'", "''"); } }
public string sTituloPlan;` ao invés de ser na variável pública.

Comment: @ismael será que isso pode ser o causador do problema? O engraçado é que o sistema funciona perfeitamente em produção...

Comment: Por isso mesmo coloquei como "anormal", não pude realizar um teste prático. Didaticamente não sei como reportar esse cenário.